# SelectMenu Customized and Refresh

Tags: jquery-ui, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I try to develop a selectMenu with image? I take exemple on jquery ui site and modify to add possibility to keep picture visible when you selected item with picture.

[Here My code](https://jsfiddle.net/wm26er7j/)

My problem is on reset. Sometimes I need to put it in initial state.

I try refresh, but there is an automatic add of With on Span result and my select change size. I correct it on create event

```
widget.css({ 'width': '' });
```

But don't Work in select event... and when I click on reset my select become smaller.

Then I try destroy event. Good for the size but not for the text display. If I select an item with picture. 
Click on reset
When I put break Point :

```
$(this).children(":first")
```

return the good item (text=TOUS") But it keeps old selected value to display text and display nothing

I don't know do to refresh correctly my selectmenu and return in first state

If debugging is the art of removing bugs ... then program is the art of creating

Comment: I see on simple selectmenu [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wm26er7j/1/) And I see when you apply selectmenu it's adding width attribue directly... But how can I stop this or correct this after refreshing?

Comment: I see [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#option-width) I try to put Width to 0 or '' but nothing run.